# Why is Arraylist<>. sublist() not mapping onto user-Defined data type arraylist<>?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Cards
{
    private int value;
    private char suit;
    public Cards()
    {
        value = 0;
        suit = '0';
    }
    private void setValue (int value)
    {
        this.value = value ;
    }
    private void setSuit (char suit)
    {
        this.suit = suit;
    }
    public int getValue ()
    {
        return value;
    }
    public char getSuit ()
    {
        return suit;
    }
    public Cards[] dealCards(int userCount)
    {
        int n = (userCount * 2)+5;
        ArrayList <Cards> pack = new ArrayList<>(52);
        for (int i=0;i<13;i++)
        {
            Cards card = new Cards ();
            for (int j=0;j<4;j++)
            {
                card.setValue (i+1);
                switch (j)
                {
                    case 0: card.setSuit('C');
                    break;
                    case 1: card.setSuit('D');
                    break;
                    case 2: card.setSuit('H');
                    break;
                    case 3: card.setSuit('S');
                    break;
                    ;
                }
                pack.add(card);
            }
        }
        Collections.shuffle(pack);
        pack = pack.sublist(0,n);
        return pack;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       int userCount = 2;
        Cards newTable[]= new Cards[(userCount*2)+5];
        newTable.dealCards(userCount);
        for(int i=0;i<(userCount *2)+5;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(newTable[i].getValue() + newTable[i].getSuit() );
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is supposed to deal a set no of unique cards. But when compiling there seems to be certain errors:

1 - the line where pack = pack.sublist(0,n)
Cannot find symbol error arises.

2 - arraylist cannot be converted to Cards [] when returning

3 - newTable. dealCards(userCount) seems to throw cannot find symbol error to. 
Is there a way to resolve these error without changing the code too much!?

Edit : after changing sublist to subList another error seemed to arise that it cannot convert list to arraylist.
Can we store the list in a array!?  Instead of and arraylist.

Comment: `1 - the line where pack = pack.sublist(0,n) Cannot find symbol error arises.`  `subList` with a capital L.

Comment: that worked but can we store store list into an array.

Comment: @NithinK Yes, using [`toArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray-T:A-). Please **read the documentation** of [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix them as follows :

> pack.sublist(0,n) Cannot find symbol error arises.

```
List<Cards> pack = new ArrayList<>(52);
pack = pack.subList(0, n); // 1
```

> arraylist cannot be converted to Cards []

```
return pack.toArray(new Cards[0]); //2
```

> newTable. dealCards(userCount) seems to throw cannot find symbol
>   error

```
Cards[] newTable = new Cards().dealCards(userCount); //3
```

Comment: @markspace ya the name was from one of the class I was testing the code with

Answer (score 2):

> 1 - the line where pack = pack.sublist(0,n) Cannot find symbol error
>   arises.

Its a typo use : `pack = pack.subList(0,n);`

> 2 - arraylist cannot be converted to Cards [] when returning

`subList` returns another list. Declare pack as :

```
List<Cards> pack = new ArrayList<>(52);
```

and then change declaration to

```
public List<Cards> dealCards(Cards[] newTable) {
```

> 3 - newTable. dealCards(userCount) seems to throw cannot find symbol
>   error to.

You can't call `dealCards()` without creating an object. To do so use :

```
Cards cards = new Cards();
cards.dealCards(newTable);
```

Now your main will look something like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int userCount = 2;
    Cards cards = new Cards();
    Cards newTable[] = new Cards[(userCount * 2) + 5];
    List<Cards> dealCards = cards.dealCards(newTable);
    for (int i = 0; i < (userCount * 2) + 5; i++) {
        System.out.println(dealCards.get(i).getValue() + dealCards.get(i).getSuit());
    }
}
```

Comment: dealCards returns a value (an array) which isn't being used here.  Shouldn't it be?

Comment: I've made the changes accordingly.